# How to find parameter $k$ from a negative binomial distribution in R?

Tags: r, distributions, negative-binomial-distribution, parameterization

I want to find the value of parameter $k$ from my data set. The data set is composed of several populations. Should I calculate the parameter $k$ for each subpopulation, or for the population at large?

I am trying to use the `fitdist(data = x, distr = "nbinom", method = "mle")` function, but I am not sure which term in this output would give the parameter $k$'s estimated value.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Fit a distribution on all the data sets? Or fit one distribution to each data set?

Comment: Fit a distribution on all data sets. So for every subpopulation I have a value k

Comment: I think we need more information about what you are trying to do and why.